# Retrieve localStorage values which start with certain words

Tags: jquery, html, storage, local

I am storing some localStorage items as follows:

```
var id = $(this).closest('.item').attr('data-id');
var title = $(this).closest('.item').attr('data-title');

var json ={"id":id,"title":title};
localStorage.setItem('clip ' +id, JSON.stringify(json));
```

Giving me…

> Key  ------------------------------ Value
>
> clip 14014_life-ring ---------- {"id":"14014_life-ring","title":"Life
>   Ring"}   clip 14015_life-jacket -------
>   {"id":"14015_life-jacket","title":"Life Jacket"}

To retrieve / display specific values, I am then using:

```
for ( var i = 0, len = localStorage.length; i < len; ++i ) {
json = localStorage.getItem( localStorage.key( i ) );

var result = JSON.parse(json);

list.append("<li><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id[]\" value=\"" + result['id'] + "\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"title[]\" value=\"" + result['title'] + "\"></li>”);

//console.log(result);
}
```

This works fine, but I also want to store some other simpler items (non JSON) as separate key / values such as input field values (by detecting keyup events) i.e, name, email address, etc.

How can I write the *for* loop above in order to only show the keys beginning with ‘clip’?

Additionally, I’d also like to be able to count only the keys beginning with ‘clip’, currently I only know how to count the total amount of *all* localStorage items which will confuse things when other items are stored…

```
$('.clip-total').html(localStorage.length);
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `if(result.indexOf('clip') === 0) { totalBeginningWithClip++; continue; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function showKeys(onlyClipKeys) {

    var totalBeginningWithClip = 0;

    for (var i = 0, len = localStorage.length; i < len; i++) {
        var key = localStorage.key(i);
        json = localStorage.getItem(key);
        console.log(key);
        var result = JSON.parse(json);

        if (onlyClipKeys) {

            if (key.indexOf('clip') === 0) {
                totalBeginningWithClip++;
                list.append("<li>" + result['id'] + " - " + result['title'] + "</li>");
            }
        } else {
            list.append("<li>" + result['id'] + " - " + result['title'] + "</li>");
        }

    }

    return totalBeginningWithClip;
}
```

Checkout [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2j58fp08/43/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time. I can't seem to get this to work? http://jsfiddle.net/2j58fp08/20/

Comment: Still not having any joy here, have used your code in this fiddle but it's not working: http://jsfiddle.net/ne0pw2eo/3/

Comment: checkout the fiddle I included

Comment: I have, tried Chrome, Safari, and Firefox – none get the <li> just an empty <ul>.